# Как сделать поиск в списке Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Есть список списков list = `[['1','Марина','1'],['1','Маша','1'],['1','Миша','1']]`
Как сделать чтобы при вводе значения `М` оставались списки у которых значений под индексом 1 начинается на букву `М` то есть: при значении `М` вывод будет `[['1','Марина','1'],['1','Маша','1'],['1','Миша','1']` при значении `Ма` вывод будет `[['1','Марина','1'],['1','Маша','1']]` при значении `Мар` вывод `[['1','Марина','1']]`

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [['1','Марина','1'],['1','Маша','1'],['1','Миша','1']]

res = [el for el in arr if el[1].startswith("Мар")]
```